# A singular regular expressions to validate multiple words

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, validation

Hello I have a text field like facebook, Instagram, Youtube, pintrest, and more like

```
<form action="" name="socialPageForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="facebook_url"  />
    <input type="text" name="twitter_url"  />
    <input type="text" name="instagram_url"  />
</form>
```

And a javascript function like

```
function validateForm() {
    var facebook_url = document.forms["socialPageForm"]["facebook_url"].value;
    if (facebook_url == "") {
        alert("Facebook Url must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know much about regular expressions but I searched on google and I found many solutions to "Validate Facebook twitter And More..."

One of them is as follow:

```
if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(url))
     return 'twitter';    

 if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
     return 'facebook';
```

But My question is: is there a way to use only a singular Regular Expression to validate all social sites?

Most of social have usernames like `facebook.com/johnDoe, twitter.com/johnDoe, instagram.com/johnDoe`; so we only have to change the name in Regular Expressions and it will apply to all social media sites.

> *It doesn't Matter it is made using php, jquery, or a javascript. `The motto is to only validate.`*

Comment: well ... there is `|` in regular expressions ... so ... yes, you can combine them (carefully)

Comment: i am not able to understand and how to use it in my `validateForm()` Function. if you help me it's really appreciated

Comment: there's a fish for you below ... no, wait, it's an answer :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will hold good for all 3 of your sites:

```
(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)(twitter|facebook|instagram)\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

Modified for `validateForm():`

```
function validateSiteURL(siteURL)
{
  var pattern = "(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)(twitter|facebook|instagram)\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"; 
  var re = new RegExp(pattern);
  if (re.test(siteURL)) 
   return true;
  return false;
}

function validateForm()
{
  //Your code...
  if(!validateSiteURL(facebook_url))
    alert("Invalid facebook URL");
}
```

Comment: how would you apply a **single** site? it's just like that ... with this regexp instead - see that code you posted with `if ... .test(...` ... that's how

Comment: like This `if (facebook_url == (https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)(twitter|facebook|instagram)\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) {` ??

Comment: Why use  `return true;   return false;` in validateSiteURL() ?

Comment: To know if the URL passed is valid or not

Comment: It will show invalid url everytime . Sorry Not Working..!

Comment: Modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks It Works...! It Also Works On `(twitter|facebook|instagram|youtube|pinterest|linkedin)`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
url = "https://facebook.com/questions/48921616/one-regular-expressions-to-validate-multiple-social-link"
r = new RegExp(/(twitter\.com|facebook\.com|linkedin\.com)/g)
is_social_link = Boolean(url.match(r))
# return value for "is_social_link" is true
```